# looping Row and scraping data taking input from excel file

Tags: python, web-scraping

i want to scrape web data using input values from excel and scraping web for each row_value taken and save the output to same excel file.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
from urllib import request
import os
import pandas as pd


ciks = pd.read_csv("ciks.csv")
ciks.head()
```

*output*

```
    CIK
0   1557822
1   1598429
2   1544670
3   1574448
4   1592290
```

then

```py
for x in ciks:
    url="https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=" + x +"&owner=exclude&action=getcompany"
    r = request.urlopen(url)
    bytecode = r.read()
    htmlstr = bytecode.decode()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(bytecode)
    t = soup.find('span',{'class':'companyName'})
    print(t.text)
```

i got an erorr : 
----> 9     print (t.text)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

here, i want to scrape web data taking each row value as input from the CSV file.

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: please add those comments to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to convert the column values as list and then use it in the for loop - see solution below,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
from urllib import request
import os
import pandas as pd
#ciks = pd.read_csv("ciks.csv")
df = pd.read_csv("ciks.csv")
mylist = df['CIK'].tolist()# CIK is the column name

company =[]
for item in mylist:
    print(item)
    url="https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=" + str(item) +"&owner=exclude&action=getcompany"
    r = request.urlopen(url)
    bytecode = r.read()
    htmlstr = bytecode.decode()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(bytecode,features="lxml")
    t = soup.find('span',{'class':'companyName'})
    company.append(t.text)
    print(t.text)
df.assign(company= company)
print(df)

df.to_csv("ciks.csv")
```